# Windows 7 - BSOD PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED and bootcat.cache is erased

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I have a computer 64-bit Windows and I keep getting the BSOD `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` message.

Yes, I've erased the Bootcat.cache file from the specified location. I don't know what else to do. I could do the Repair your Computer option from the Advanced Boot Options or Recovery Disc but it keeps happening after every computer restart...

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft KB981833](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981833).

> To resolve this problem, apply Service Pack 1 for Windows 7.
> **Microsoft  provides no supported hotfix for this problem**. For more
> information  about this service pack, click the following article
> number to view  the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> - [976932](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976932)
>   Information about  Service Pack 1 for Windows 7.